# How to trigger ng-change in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I'm new to both angularjs and angularjs. 
Currently I'm working on a phantomjs script that access an angularjs application that consists of list of ng-change. I need to trigger this ng-change in order to get the correct data on the div in order for screen capture.
How can I trigger ng-change in phantomjs?

```
        <ul class="list list-unstyled"
            ng-repeat="site in availableSites.sites |
                filter:searchFilter |
                orderBy:'site_name'">
            <li>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio"
                               ng-model="selections.siteID"
                               ng-value="site.site_id"
                               ng-change="changeSite(site.site_name)"
                               name="site">
                        {{site.site_name}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

It doesn't work when I try this in the phantomjs script:

```
        var siteSelection = document.querySelector('input[value="1007"]');
        var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent("change", false, true);
        siteSelection.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Where have you put your *triggering* code? Maybe you dispatch an event before the input will be compiled and linked by angularjs.